# The provided cwd "C:\laravel projects\eccomer/../public_html" does not exist

Tags: laravel

when i try to run serve in laravel i got this error

> Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException
>
> The provided cwd "C:\laravel projects\eccomer/../public_html" does
> not exist.
>
> at C:\laravel
> projects\eccomer\vendor\symfony\process\Process.php:344
> 340▕             }
> 341▕         }
> 342▕
> 343▕         if (!is_dir($this->cwd)) {   ➜ 344▕             throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('The provided cwd "%s" does not exist.',
> $this->cwd));
> 345▕         }
> 346▕
> 347▕         $this->process = @proc_open($commandline, $descriptors, $this->processPipes->pipes, $this->cwd, $envPairs,
> $this->options);
> 348▕
>
> 1   C:\laravel
> projects\eccomer\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:128
> Symfony\Component\Process\Process::start(Object(Closure))
>
> 2   C:\laravel
> projects\eccomer\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand.php:68
> Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ServeCommand::startProcess()

i try anything but does not work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed error like this :
in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php file in boot funcation i copy this code:

```
 public function boot()
    {
        Paginator::useBootstrap();
    }
```

and my problem fixed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).